# ERC20 token transfer is not working in Ethereum private Blockchain (contract to contrcat call)

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, private-blockchain

When I am trying to call ERC20 token **transfer** function from another contract (contract to contract call) in ethereum private blockchain network is not working, but if I try to call directly from js it's working.

Below I have shown the contract and js call.

**ERC20.sol**

```
function transfer(address sender, address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public returns (bool) 
{
    require(numTokens <= balances[admin]);
    balances[admin] = balances[admin].sub(numTokens);
    balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
    emit Transfer(admin, receiver, numTokens);
    return true;
}
```

**ABcontract.sol**

```
function tokentransfer(address sender, address receiver) public returns (bool) {
    ERC20Basic instance = ERC20Basic(erc20address);
    instance.transfer(sender,account,1000);
    return true;
}
```

**app.js**

```
tokentransfer:function(){
    ABcontract.deployed().then(function(instance){
      instance.tokentransfer(sender,receiver,{from:sender,gas:4600000});
    })
},
```

Sender have 1000 tokens by using ERC20 **createtoken** function.

```
Truffle v4.1.15 (core: 4.1.15)
Solidity v0.4.25 (solc-js)
node v10.19.0
Network : Private blockchain (Note:It's working in testrpc)
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your oldest version of  ethereum privatenet blockchain.
Update and upgrade your geth,go and truffle versions.

Comment: This is unlikely to be a correct answer.